# How to call an Erlang function in Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

What is the format to call an Erlang function in Elixir?

Specifically, how can I call the function in `iex` and where can I find a list of modules and functions available from Erlang.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First find the module and function you want to call in the [Erlang OTP Reference Page Index](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man_index.html).

For example to call random uniform you would look in the **random** module and find the uniform\0 function.

To call that in Elixir you use the format, `:module.function()`, e.g.,

```
iex(1)> :random.uniform()
0.7230402056221108
```

For functions that do not take any parameters the parenthesis are optional.

Comment: The point is you call the functions normally, the only difference is that Elixir modules have `CamelCaseNames` while erlang modules have `:snake_case_names_with_a_colon`

Comment: Don't forget the important point @Gerry that Elixir strings which are denoted with "string" need to be changed to char lists when passed to Erlang like 'string'  I'd add that to your answer.

Comment: @gerry the updated URL for the link to the OTP Reference Page Index is: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man_index.html . I attempted to update your answer, but I got the "too many edits in queue" error.

Answer (score 4):

The autocomplete in iex will help a lot with this.

```
iex> :c<TAB>
```

will show you all the loaded modules from Erlang that start with the letter 
c, and

```
iex> :crypto.<TAB>
```

will show you all the functions available in that module. Unfortunately as of Elixir 1.2 the h command does not yet work for Erlang modules. It does have a useful side effect though.

Not all the available Erlang modules are loaded initially (there are over 500 in the standard Erlang distribution). One way to get a module loaded is to use the `h` command.

```
iex> h :crypto
```

Or you could just use the `l` command, but that's not nearly as fun.

Answer (score 1):

[erldocs.com](http://erldocs.com) allow you to interactively search the Erlang documentation.

Manpages are also convenient (just `man <module-name>` in your shell), if you have them installed. For this, I recommend [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl), which can install Erlang manpages automatically with the right config.

Shameless plug to my project:
`h` on Erlang functions / modules in IEx doesn't work, but the hope is it will thanks to [docsh](https://github.com/erszcz/docsh).